# Multiple inheritance, combined functionality

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a basic class of algorithm named `DE`. It has 2 implemented methods: `a()`, `b()`. I would like to test a variation of this algorithm, named `DEa`. So, I'm doing `DEa extends DE` and I override method `a()`. There is another variation, algorithm `DEb`. I'm doing the same, `DEb extends DE` and overriding `b()`. Now, I want to test algorithm `DEab`. Here is the problem. If I write `DEab extends DEa` it will already have overridden method `a()`, but not `b()`, I would have to copy `b()` from `DEb`, which is ugly and harder to maintain.

Code example:

```
class DE { int i; void a() { i = 1; } void b() { i++; } };
class DEa extends DE { void a() { i = 2; } };
class DEb extends DE { void b() { i--; } };
// class DEab extends DEa, DEb - can't write like this
class DEab extends DEa { void b() { i-- }; } // but this is copy-paste :c
```

I tried with `interface A`, `interface B` and later `DE implements A, B`, `DEa extends DE`, `DEb extends DE`... and it's basically the same problem:

```
interface A { void a(); } // methods in interfaces must be abstract
interface B { void b(); } 
class DE implements A, B { int i; void a() { i = 1; } void b() { i++; } };
class DEa extends DE { void a() { i = 2; } };
class DEb extends DE { void b() { i--; } }; 
class DEab extends // ... well it give me nothing
```

How to do it without copy-paste?

Comment: Composition is often a more straightforward  solution than multiple inheritance. Break the A and B parts out into separate components that then are used to implement the different DEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern.

```
public interface A {
    public void a();
}

public interface B {
    public void b();
}

public class ABComposition implements A, B {    
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public ABComposition(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void a() {
        a.a();      
    }

    @Override
    public void b() {
        b.b();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the assumption here is that the `A` instance and the `B` instance are both constructed in such a way that they have access to the common state (`i`).

Answer (score 2):

No multiple inheritance in Java. You can only have multiple interfaces implemented (you provide the implementation), but only one (direct) superclass.

You can use composition anyway, by making

```
 public class DEab extends DE {
   private DEa dea = new DEa();
   private DEb deb = new DEb();
   public int a() {
     return dea.a();
   }

   public int b() {
     return deb.b();
   }
 }
```

if the logic of your class supports it.

UPDATE: After the update of the question, I stick with the simpler "no, Java does not support multiple inheritance"

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you had in mind.  The two instances (of `DEa` and `DEb`) would not share state (in this case `i`).

Comment: @ArthurDent that is exactly the issue that I had in mind when I stated `if the logic of your class supports it`.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment about shared state assumption I can propose you refactored version of @Toilal's approach:

```
interface A {
    public int a();
}

interface B {
    public int b(int i);
}

class DEa implements A {
    @Override
    public int a() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class DEb implements B {
    @Override
    public int b(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }
}

class DE {
    private int i;
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public DE(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void a() {
        i = a.a();
    }

    public void b() {
        i = b.b(i);
    }
}
```

In this case `DEa` and `DEb` is logic providers and `DE` is a state provider. Now you can inject any kind of logic implementors to `DE` and receive state from it.